# Using collections instead of classes

Tags: java, android, oop

I have a Web Service in java and in my website I need to show some reports. Tables with header and data. These reports will be showed in a Android app as well. 
The question is, for every report, that is about something different, like a report about Cars and other about Dogs, I need to create a model class to do this the right way?

For example (this is a simple example), if I need to show stats about cars, I might have a java object like this one:

```
public class CarStats {
    private String carName;
    private String carModel;
    private int unitsSold;
}
```

So in my website and Android app I need to implement a table with specific headers. This seems to me like the right approach, because I think this approach follows OO.

On the other hand if I wanted to make this generic, would be better use a object like this:

```
public class GenericData {
    private List<String> headers;
    private List<List<String>> data;
}
```

With that approach I only need to create a only table to handle this object, both in my website and android app no matter about what is the data I'm showing (much easier).

But this second approach does not feels right to me. And I would like to know what approach is better.

What are the pros and cons of both methods?

Thanks.

Comment: You seem to have a couple of good answers to your question already. You can continue asking more questions in the comments to these answers or accept one of the answers as the accepted one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think two meaning of "generic" has got mixed up. One is Java Generics such as using parametrized type `<T>`. The other is generic in the ordinary sense of English language. You may need the second one, not the first one. In this sense, generic means you create some sort of structure that fits different data, not `<T>` thing.

For example, instead of CarStat you may create a generic Stat or Data class (you chose the appropriate name).

```
public class Report {
    private String header;
    private String data;
    ...
    private String footnote;
    ...
}

Report carReport = Report ("Car", "Data about the car ...", ...); 
// send carReport to be presented.
...
Report dogReport = Report ("Dog", "Data about the dog...", ...);
```

Now, in your presentation layer you care only about the structure of the table. Then you can present any content provided by web service without worrying about if it is a car or dog or something else.

Comment: I ended up using your idea of a Report class with some modifications. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have n different entities & plan on making a single class, then all the entities should have the same structure. Say if you have a Car & a Dog. Your CarStats class has carName, carModel etc. But for the Dog class you will certainly have different fields right? Instead of a carModel you will have dogBreed & a property for dog's age.

```
public class Car {
    private String carName;
    private String carModel;
    private int unitsSold;
}
```

for Dog

```
public class Dog {
    private String dogName;
    private String dogBreed;
    private int numAdopted;
    private int age;
}
```

Only if all the different entity classes have the same class properties & methods then creating a Generic class makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

> What are the pros and cons of both methods?

You should not use the second approach for a problem definition of this nature. The purpose of a `Collection` in Java is to hold a group of related objects together. A class on the other hand is a blueprint from which other objects are created. These objects can be put in a `Collection`but they can't be replaced by it.

As far as the pros of using a class instead of a `Collection` are concerned,  there are plenty but one simple example will be good enough to cover them all :

```
public class CarStats {
    private String carName;
    private String carModel;
    private int unitsSold;

    public void setName(String carName) { 
          if(name==null || name.isEmpty())  {
              System.out.println("name cannot be empty"); 
          }
    }

    public void toString() {
         return "Name : "+carName+" "+carModel+"unitsSold "+unitsSold;
    }

}
```

As simple as it may look, there is so much happening in the above code. Named variables, encapsulation, modularity, readability, self-sufficiency, etc. How would you go about achieving these goals when using a `Collection`?

Let's say that you still decide to go ahead with the second approach, the below code should be enough for you to reconsider :

**1. Usage when using a class :**

```
Car car = new Car();
String name = getNameFromSomewhere();
car.setName(name);
System.out.println(name);
```

**2. Usage when using a collection**

```
GenericData data = new GenericData();
genericData.getHeaders().add("name","model","unitsSold");
String name = getNameFromSomewhere();
genericData.getData().get(0).add(name);
System.out.println(genericData.getData().get(0).get(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on your data. Maybe if you only show tables for cars and dogs you should make classes for them. But if your app  does not care about the difference you should probably not implement them in the app. If your app will just display a table then you should implement the "Table"  as your object and just display it. The server could just deliver a TableMessage to you and If you need a representation of a Car and a Dog then the server can know this and do the mapping. This also has the advantage that you can add new data entities later without touching your clients.

Comment: Yes, if the app does not know about the data its much easier to add new reports. But others things are at stake here: if I use the generic objects how can I show that in my app? If I use a RecyclerView I will need to add views dinamically to each row and this does not seems really good because I will not be able to recycle these views.

Comment: If your app displays a CarItem differently than a DogItem than you might want to have separate classes for them. If you just need a TableItem and display them in the same way a generic approach might be better. It really depends on how much the client needs to care about the difference. I do not understand why you think it would be harder to recycle the generic item. If the views are similar you can just recycle them in both approaches.To clarify what I mean by generic approach: e.g. a TableItemMessage that contains category, title, description, imageurl, etc...

Comment: I say it would be harder because I don't know for sure how many views (TextView specifically) I will need per row.